# Parentheses show in standard Overleaf font but not in custom SegoeUI.ttf Font (they are in the ttf file)

Tags: fonts

I changed my Font using the following code in my preamble. It works perfectly fine.

```
\setmainfont[ExternalLocation=../4-Fonts/]{SegoeUI.ttf}[
BoldFont={SegoeUIBold.ttf},
ItalicFont={SegoeUIItalic.ttf},
BoldItalicFont={SegoeUIBoldItalic.ttf}
]
```

However () and "" do not get compiled. The Font package has () and such in it. [image: SegoeUI.ttf FILE]

When I comment the above code out of my preamble and the text goes back to its standard font all () and "" get compiled correctly.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
%Document language
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%Better line spacing
\usepackage{microtype}

%Document margins and size
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2.3cm,right=2.3cm,headheight=15pt]{geometry}

%Write in color
\usepackage{xcolor}

%Useful math package
\usepackage{amsmath}

%PDF links and hyperlinks https://www.namsu.de/Extra/pakete/Hyperref.html
\usepackage{hyperref}

%better tables
\usepackage{array}

%citations
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}

%better quotes (recommended by bibtex)
\usepackage{csquotes}

%Better Images
\usepackage{tikz}

%better headers https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Headers_and_footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%date and time
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}

%reference for lastpage number
\usepackage{lastpage}

%enables font selection and sets main font
\usepackage{fontspec}



%Best loaded last in the preamble (for subfiles)
\usepackage{subfiles} 



%defines the path to find images
\graphicspath{{../2-Images}}

%sets main and secondary font
\setmainfont[ExternalLocation=../4-Fonts/]{SegoeUI.ttf}[
BoldFont={SegoeUIBold.ttf},
ItalicFont={SegoeUIItalic.ttf},
BoldItalicFont={SegoeUIBoldItalic.ttf}
]
\begin{document}
\section{intro}

  the formatting and (numbering is handled)"" automatically according to the template you've chosen. If you're using Rich Text mode, you can also create new section and subsections via the buttons in the editor toolbar.
\end{document}
```

I do not get any errors or warnings related to that. This is what they get shown as. [image]

Edit2: In the log files it says that my ttf file does not have the symbols. Although it does not throw a error or a warning. Could that be overleaf related?

They should be there though as the picture above displays paretheses so it must be in the ttf file.

Comment: don't just show a snippet show a document ending with (say) `\begin{document} (abc)\end{document}` and show the log that you get "do not get compiled" is not enough information, what error do you get?

Comment: I edted the post